# Where does the shebang in tool-launching Python scripts come from?

Tags: python, pip, package, shebang

Several widely used Python tools — such as `pip`, `yolk` and `ipython` — are launched by scripts with a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) specifying what Python instance should be used to run them. How is the contents of this line determined?

---

For example, on OS X machine, where I have been using Apple's Python, this line reads

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

What would happen if I installed the python.org version, which is placed in

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/python
```

with a symlink at

```
/usr/local/bin/python
```

and then updated or re-installed a tool? If I updated a tool would the line change? Would I have to fully reinstall (rather than simply updating) each tool to force a change? What would the line change to? Would it be

```
#!/usr/local/bin
```

or

```
#!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
```

Is there a way to make it

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Comment: I think you mean `#!/usr/local/bin/python` and not just `#!/usr/local/bin` above.

Comment: @Joe: Correct. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

The line comes from the [`sys.executable` value](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.executable).

If you symlink the python executable, and run Python from that symlink, `sys.executable` would use the new path. Updating or reinstalling the tool would reflect the changed executable path, yes.

I am not aware of any method to make `pip` and friends use `#!/usr/bin/env python` instead. That'd be a bad idea, really, as that would make it harder to use the correct Python all the time, the one where the installed packages can be found needed to run the command-line script.

Comment: When, say `pip` is run to do an upgrade or re-install, and uses `/usr/local/bin` as indicated by the shebang. Will the value of ` sys.executable` (for that invocation of `pip`) be `/usr/local/bin`, or will it be the path to the Python that will run at the command prompt (i.e., the Python returned by `which`)?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: `pip` is itself a command-line tool, so it has a shebang line too. You'd need to update *that* line first, or run `pip` with the Python interpreter of choice (`/usr/local/bin/python /path/to/pip/script/pip.py`).

Comment: So in effect, if I've got `pip` with a given shebang and just run it "naked" at the command line, it (and all tools I have installed with a past version of Python) will continue to use that (old) version? But once I run `pip` to update *itself* (once) using an explicit version of Python (as in your comment above, or by editing the script to do so), all subsequent updates of *any* tools by `pip` will fix their shebangs too?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: exactly. Then Python will be started with a new path, and that becomes `sys.executable`.

Comment: And (just to be sure) is it sufficient to `sudo /path_to/correct_version pip install -U pip` (just once) to get `pip` to use "correct_version" on all subsequent runs of `pip`  (i.e., change the shebang in `pip.py`) so that subsequently `sudo pip install -U package` will change the shebang for "package", or is it more involved than that?

Comment: Mee too! I was going to accept. I haven't tested this yet, but it sure *sounds* right.